# Serverless Titan graph stack with AWS DynamoDB and Lambda

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, titan, gremlin, serverless-framework

As announced [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-store-and-process-graph-data-using-the-dynamodb-storage-backend-for-titan/), it is possible to use Titan with DynamoDB as its backend.

Is it possible to build a serverless Titan Graph DB stack that is accessed via AWS Lambda functions?

Theoretically there should be nothing stoping this implementation but I couldn't find any example. There had been a [discussion on the issue](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/issues/41) under the code repository but did not yield anything concrete yet.

Comment: I don't know Titan very well, but it seems that the answer for your question is "yes". You could run AWS Lambda with Java and access Titan using its API. You just need to deploy the Lambda function with all dependencies.

Comment: Side note: DynamoDB is *not* a serverless database. When you need to worry about servers (provisioning capacity and paying without using) it's not considered as serverless. However, DynamoDB is a very nice managed database that is largely used as the database of serverless projects.

Comment: @Zanon, maybe the cost of bringing up a Titan instance for a single Lambda operation is too high but I couldn't find any reference for that.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but I have not estimated the latency considerations involved in starting Titan in a Lambda function. For high request rates, write loads may not be appropriate as each lambda container will try to secure one range of ids from the titan_ids table and you may run out of ids quickly. If your requests are read-only, one way to reduce Titan launch time is to open the graph in read-only mode. In read-only mode, Titan does not need to get an id range lease from titan-ids either.

Comment: in my case the write load is very low; ≈ 1 write / hour. so the read-only mode sounds like a good idea. i'll look into it.